# Connection refused to host exception in java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

When I tried to communicate with server using RMI the following exception occurred

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host : 172.16.7.229; nested exception is:
     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at SI_Stub.add(Unknown Source)
     at RC.main(RC.java:15) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
     at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
     ... 6 more
```

Note: I am not using port, I have already started the rmiregistry.

Comment: Please give some more information and post your code where the exception is occurring.

Comment: Is `172.16.7.229` the IP address you expected to connect to? If not, see item A.1 of the RMI FAQ.

Comment: And what does 'I am not using port' mean?

Comment: Run the below command `netstat -aon | find "1099"` on WIndows or `netstat -aon | grep 1099` on linux and verify if the port is listening.

Comment: @Andrews If it wasn't, the `lookup()` that must have preceded this call would not have succeeded.